# Is RabbitMQ capable of passing messages to specific clients? Or must I perform those checks client-side?

Tags: python, networking, rabbitmq

I have my software running on a bunch of clients around my network. I've been playing around with RabbitMQ as a solution for passing messages between each client.

My test code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import pika
import time

connection = pika.AsyncoreConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
                 'localhost'))
channel    = connection.channel()

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    # send messages back on certain events
    if body == '5':
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                              routing_key='test',
                              body='works')

    print body

channel.queue_declare(queue='test')
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='test', no_ack=True)

for i in range(0, 8):
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                          routing_key='test',
                          body='{}'.format(i))

    time.sleep(0.5)

channel.close()
```

Picture this as kind of a 'chat program'. Each client will need to constantly listen for messages. At times, the client will need to send messages back to the server.

This code works, but I've ran into an issue. When the code below sends out the message `works`, it then retreives that again from the RabbitMQ queue. Is there a way to tell have my client, a producer and a consumer, not receive the message it just sent?

I can't see this functionality built into RabbitMQ so I figured I'd send messages in the form of:

```
body='{"client_id" : 1, "message" : "this is the message"}'
```

Then I can parse that string and check the `client_id`. The client can then ignore all messagess not destined to it.

Is there a better way? Should I look for an alternative to RabbitMQ?

Comment: Did you come to some conclusion on this matter?

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many queue in RabbitMQ. Why not have a queue for messages to the server as well as a queue for each client?